# ng-show is not working even though $scope variable is true

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why is my div still have ng-hide even though ng-show is true, well at least the scope show it is true. I am not sure what happen here

html file

```
        <div class="agent-content-wrapper" ng-controller="LoaCtrl">
            <div class="list-of-agent">
                <div class="loa-header">List of Agents</div>
                <div class="agent-list" ng-repeat="agent in ListOfAgents">
                    <div class="agent-main-list">
                        <div class="agent" ng-click="goToAgentRecords(agent)">{{agent.name}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="agent-details" ng-show="IsAgentSelected" ></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

js file

```
$scope.IsAgentSelected = false;
$scope.goToAgentRecords = function (agent) {
    $scope.IsAgentSelected = true;
}
```

Comment: are you referring to this *empty* div? `<div class="agent-details" ng-show="IsAgentSelected" ></div>`

Comment: yes, div.agent-details, it is empty but I specify the height and width already.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/GCs6wJSQP8Wws9aMgXMn?p=preview check what's gone wrong in your code, and if you need to hide the div in second click and show it in next click probably the *goToAgentRecords* should change as below *$scope.IsAgentSelected = !$scope.IsAgentSelected;*

Answer (score 0):

For me it is working fine,
Kindly write something inside ng-show div to see effect of it.

My code is mentioned below:

index.html

```
<div class="agent-content-wrapper" ng-controller="LoaCtrl">
            <div class="list-of-agent">
                <div class="loa-header">List of Agents</div>
                <div class="agent-list" ng-repeat="agent in ListOfAgents">
                    <div class="agent-main-list">
                        <div class="agent" ng-click="goToAgentRecords(agent)">{{agent}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {{IsAgentSelected}}
                <div class="agent-details" ng-show="IsAgentSelected" >Display Ng- Show</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Controller.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('LoaCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
$scope.ListOfAgents =['a','b','c']
$scope.IsAgentSelected = false;
$scope.goToAgentRecords = function (agent) {
    $scope.IsAgentSelected = true;
}
}]);
```

I have printed value of IsAgentSelected in div to see its proper value, you can remove it after it works normal.
If still it is not working kindly comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. It is working now after a while. I dont understand why it is not working earlier.